# Check multiple strings (from a file) against HTML text with Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, find, scrapy

I need to check a scrapped HTML document against multiple strings from a text file, in Python. In different words, The spider should find out if the html text contains any of given strings.

```
    url = 'http://forum.unisoftdev.com'
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    html = response.read()


    with open('keywords.txt') as f:
        key_words = f.readlines()

    # here's the nut:
    if key_words in html :
        # do something
```

I don't want any "elif" and "else" because I need it in a text file, so I have to check the document against multiple strings but don't know how to do it in Python. In PHP it's really easier...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with alternations to check if any keyword is present in your input text. Just join the keywords with [alternations](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) together.

```
pattern = "|".join(r'{}'.format(word) for word in key_words)
```

If you do not want substring matches, e.g. match omegaforce by omega, then you will need to add [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
pattern = "|".join(r'\b{}\b'.format(word) for word in key_words)
```

Sample Code:

```
import re
html = 'I have lots of deltas but no omegas'
key_words = ['alpha', 'omega','delta']
pattern = "|".join(r'{}'.format(word) for word in key_words)
rx = re.compile(pattern)
if rx.search(html):
    # do something
    print "found"
```